# How to connect two Android devices over GPRS or 3G?

Tags: android

I want to connect two phones over 3G or GPRS to send a stream of data continually. One phone will act as client that will send data and the other phone will act as the server to receive and display the same data. Is it possible to stream data without using a server?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid and on-topic development question; only appropriate reason for closing would be if someone wants to dig up one of the likely duplicates.

Comment: I read this question as: one device *calls* the other device (like analog modems or faxes used to call each other in the old days) and set up a 1-to-1 data connection. But all the answers are assuming both devices simply have their internet connection and talking about TCP / UDP packets.

Comment: I think Red Panda app does this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.redPanda         It's code - https://github.com/redPanda-project/android

Answer (score 1):

No. You will have to use some kind of server definitely.

Comment: Thank u every1. Can any1 please let me know how to connect two phones over 3G or GPRS, so as to transfer a stream of data from one phone to another using a server.? please explain step by step as i am a learner yet.

Comment: Depends on the kind of data you'd like to stream. What are you planning to stream?

Comment: i want to stream numbers. pls help me

Comment: If it's something like that you may want to look into Google Cloud Messaging API.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, I have been working on a similar project using TCP/UDP packets, but the big issue is with finding the other phone.

The best way is to use a system similar to O-Auth to connect with an external server on the internet
and send/recive data through that, but I don't have much experience with that.

My project used UDP to find a server on a wifi network and get its ip, then connect to it through tcp, 
but you just as easily use a server on the web to do it over any mobile data connection.

If you wanted I will gladly send you some of my tcp code as a starting point.
Swift

Comment: Actually, no you can't use the same techniques from wifi with a mobile connection, as most mobile providers block incoming connections.

Comment: Thats not quite right, some providers use NAT firewalls to change udp ports, but you can keep it open by sending a blank packet every 30 secs.

Comment: keep it open, yes, that's what lets UDP back and forth to a "server" work.  But you can't open it in the first place from the outside.  Both phones have to create outgoing connections or initial UDP packets, so there has to be a server for them to go to - they cannot initiate communication between themselves without server help.

Comment: Thats what I have stated, I have said you need a external server for them to connect through

Comment: So your answer to the question if it can be done without a server is a "No" rather than the "Yes" that you wrote.

Comment: Updated answer, I see what you mean now, brain just slightly hazy after long day, sorry for any trouble

Comment: Thank u every1. Can any1 please let me know how to connect two phones over 3G or GPRS, so as to transfer a stream of data from one phone to another using a server.? please explain step by step as i am a learner yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect two devices directly though the cellular data. You need an intermediate server.

If on the other hand you are going to connect them through wifi, then you can use sockets to connect both of them together.

If the distance between both the devices is less, then you can also try out transfer over bluetooth.

Comment: Thank u every1. Can any1 please let me know how to connect two phones over 3G or GPRS, so as to transfer a stream of data from one phone to another using a server.? please explain step by step as i am a learner yet.